# $|z^2-n^2| \ge C(y^2 +n^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $E=\{x+iy: |x|\le 1/2, |y|\ge 1\}.$ Show that there exists a positive constant $C$ such that

$$|z^2-n^2| \ge C(y^2 +n^2)$$

for all $z\in E,n\in \mathbb N.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$|z^2-n^2| =|x^2-y^2+i2xy-n^2| \ge |x^2-y^2-n^2| = y^2-x^2+n^2 \ge y^2-1/4+n^2.$$

Thus

$$\frac{|z^2-n^2|}{y^2 + n^2}  \ge 1-\frac{1/4}{y^2+n^2}\ge \frac{3}{4}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was so helpful. But It is not clear to me how you were able to drop $|2xy|$. Could you please explain?

Comment: It's because $|a+ib|\ge |a|$ if $a,b$ are real.

Comment: More explicitly, $|a+ib| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \ge \sqrt{a^2} = |a|$. Also $|a+ib| \ge |b|$.

Comment: Thank you guys! Got it.